# MDX filtering by multiple dimension members

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

**Problem**

I need to create a report which will list a number of accounts that match certain criteria - `simulationDate`, `statisticPeriod`, `region`.

Right now my query looks like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Count] as 1
SELECT [Measures].[Count] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
Crossjoin(
[Account].[Account Number].ALLMEMBERS,
{[simulationDate].[day].&[10010101]},
{[statisticPeriod].[period].&[201201]},
{[region].[code].&[SO]}
)
ON COLUMNS
FROM [myWH]
```

Is this cross-dimensional filtering okay?

Comment: Do you want to apply some form of filtering? You might like to detail the criteria that you'd like to apply for the filtering. If you do a cross-join with Non-Empty then a certain amount of filtering will be taken care of automatically e.g. only account number x will appear with dates that exist for that particular account. This is called auto-exist behaviour.

Comment: @whytheq yep, I wanted to filter by simulationDate, statisticPeriod and region. I might try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I ended up using the filters as my columns, and letting the NON EMPTY clause take care of the filtering:

```
SELECT 
 NON EMPTY 
    {[simulationDate].[day].&[10010101]} *
    {[statisticPeriod].[period].&[201201]} *
    {[region].[code].&[SO]}
 ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY
    [Account].[Account Number].ALLMEMBERS 
 ON ROWS
FROM [myWH]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is slightly more modern using the `*` notation instead of the `Crossjoin` function:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Count] AS 1 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Count] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [Account].[Account Number].ALLMEMBERS*
      {[simulationDate].[day].&[10010101]}*
      {[statisticPeriod].[period].&[201201]}*
      {[region].[code].&[SO]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [myWH];
```

I'm assuming that your custom measure `[Measures].[Count]` is just a place-holder?

This table will be very wide if you have that cross-join on `COLUMNS` but that might just be a typo:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Count] AS 1 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Count] ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY 
      [Account].[Account Number].ALLMEMBERS*
      {[simulationDate].[day].&[10010101]}*
      {[statisticPeriod].[period].&[201201]}*
      {[region].[code].&[SO]} ON ROWS
FROM [myWH];
```

You have added the keywords `NON EMPTY` in front of the rows cross-join. This is telling the processor to exclude any rows that are empty - empty for `[Measures].[Count]` ....but this measure is *never* empty it is always equal to 1. So the following without `Non Empty` should return exactly the same result:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Count] AS 1 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Count] ON COLUMNS, 
      [Account].[Account Number].ALLMEMBERS*
      {[simulationDate].[day].&[10010101]}*
      {[statisticPeriod].[period].&[201201]}*
      {[region].[code].&[SO]} ON ROWS
FROM [myWH];
```

So in terms of filtering you aren't doing any - what sort of filtering do you need? If you replace `[Measures].[Count]` with an actual measure from your cube and use the NON EMPTY then you should see a lot less rows:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[ReplaceWithActualMeasure] ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY
      [Account].[Account Number].ALLMEMBERS*
      {[simulationDate].[day].&[10010101]}*
      {[statisticPeriod].[period].&[201201]}*
      {[region].[code].&[SO]} ON ROWS
FROM [myWH];
```