# Add multiple calculating filters in MDX

Tags: filter, ssas, mdx

I am really new to MDX but I have spent the past two days looking for an answer but failed. So I greatly appreciate your help and patience.

I am trying to query a Cube with filters on multiple dimensions, and I realize that there are many similar questions already there, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865118/mdx-filter-multiple-dimensions) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940628/mdx-filtering-by-multiple-dimension-members).

The thing is, instead of specifying a particular content I am looking for, I am trying to set up filters that picks up all records that begins with a specific string. This requires `left` function in the filters (i.e. calculating filters?) but I cannot blend them nicely into the code.

My failed code is like this (the two filters should be in `AND`relation)

```
Select Non Empty ([Measures].[Sales]) ON 0
FROM [Cube_Name]
WHERE
(
FILTER
(
[Customer].[CustomerID].Members, Left([Customer].[CustomerID].CurrentMember.Name,4)="ABCD"),
[Product].[ProductID].Members, Left([Product].[ProductID].CurrentMember.Name,3)="EFG")
)
)
```

(My trial is based on the last answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865118/mdx-filter-multiple-dimensions).)

I also read that there are some workarounds like `CROSSJOIN` `WITH` `AGGREGATE` or Sub-`SELECT`, but I just do not have any clue on 1)how to incorporate the conditions inside; 2) performance (I heard that `CROSSJOIN` can be slow).

I am not sure if I should mention it here, but I am actually implementing the MDX from Excel VBA by using the `ADOMB.Cellset` object. It only gives me the Grand total of the query I implemented under `Cellset.Items(0)` (there are no more items).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split two sets into two filters:

```
Select 
Non Empty [Measures].[Sales] on 0
From [Cube_Name]
Where
(
    Filter(
        [Customer].[CustomerID].[CustomerID].Members, 
        Left(
            [Customer].[CustomerID].CurrentMember.Name,
            4
        ) = "ABCD"
    ),
    Filter(
        [Product].[ProductID].[ProductID].Members, 
        Left(
            [Product].[ProductID].CurrentMember.Name,
            3
        ) = "EFG"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you Danylo! Your code works perfectly! Would you mind telling me one more thing about how to incorporate the OR clause in the filter?

I tried to modify the second filter into

`Filter(
        [Product].[ProductID].[ProductID].Members, 
        Left(
            [Product].[ProductID].CurrentMember.Name,
            3
        ) = "EFG" OR
       Left(
            [Product].[ProductID].CurrentMember.Name,
            3
        ) = "HIJ"
)`
but it does not work. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry it seems that the OR conjunction works. It's just one of my typos that results in the error message. But thank you again for the timely and accurate response!